Jquery redirect to another page with specific ID not working
$("#createContractBtn").on("click", function(e) { 
   e.preventDefault() 
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#contractLstTable").offset()}, {
     duration: 1500,
     complete: function() {
        window.location = "{{ route('searchEnquiry', app()->getLocale()) }}?xxx=" + encryptedXXX;
     }
   });
})

I am trying to redirect to another page and have the page automatically scroll to its specific id of the page but it is not working even I tried different kinds of solutions. What is the possible way to have the page automatically scroll to specific ID while I clicked the button?
I have tried to modify the code with different ways but the scrolling effect still does not work

the approach you are using is performing the redirect at the very end and once you landed on the new page the javascript has no more control over that document. You may instead use a different strategy. An URL may have a so called hash property targeting the id of the element where to scroll to. So for example if you wish to open a page scrolling to a given element, it's enough to point the anchor to http://host/page#idOfTheElement and the new page will be loaded and scrolled to such element

Yes I did try adding #+id but it also does not work as I am using PHP blade

If you instead you wish to have more fined control on the scroll, you'll need each of those page to be aware of that behaviour and accept a query parameter that will instruct the details of the behviour

no classname.. it must be the id and only the id will work. it's a web standard and the browser knows that when the url contains that part it means the page must be loaded and scrolled to that element having that id

So how can I put the id to have the redirected page automatically scroll to that id?

yes but I hope you got the point.. you don't need special javascript... you just move the location to an url containing as its last part #idoftheelement. You may even try on the address bar.. if by hand you write an url with that fragment added, the page loaded will be scrolled to that element

How about if I originally have the query param?

I think you should better focus the question and comments went too far... I can just make my words more clear (if they weren't very clear already) by adding a concrete url with such feature and you'll see with your eyes by clicking on it: URL - Instance properties (by the way yes as you can see it works also if the url contains GET parameters)

@MERNStackDeveloper instead of doing it using jquery, better to create link with the#parameter

How about if I redirect in javascript as I submit the form post data and redirect to another page?
